# Allow a folder and disallow all sub folders in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I would like to allow folder `/news/` and disallow all the sub folders under `/news/` e.g. `/news/abc/`, `/news/123/`. How can I do that please?

I think `Disallow: /news/` will block everything in it, including `/news/` itself.

Will `Disallow: /news/*/` do the job, since there is no easy way to test it, I want to make sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /news/$
Disallow: /news/
```

Explanation:

Google's `robots.txt` spec (https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt), which is more up to date than the "official" spec, states that:

*`/fish/` will match anything in the `/fish/` folder but will not match `/fish`* (and, no wildcard necessary, since *"The trailing slash means this matches anything in this folder."*) If you kinda reverse engineer that:

`User-agent: *` (or whatever user agent you want to talk to)
`Allow: /news/$` (allows `/news/` but the `$` character says the allow can't go beyond `/news/`)
`Disallow: /news/` (disallows anything in the `/news/` folder)

Test it in Google Search Console, or in Yandex (https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/robotstxt/) to ensure it works for your site.

Comment: I tried this at the root level to allow all webpages to be crawled but to block all directories i.e.:
`User-agent: *`
`Allow: /$`
`Disallow: /`

And tested it via the google search console but https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php was blocked. Does this need to be different at root level?

Comment: I have answered my own question:
`User-agent: *`
`Disallow: /*/`

Comment: Yep. You can even do just: `Disallow: /*` (because the final slash comes after the wildcard anyway, which covers the slash).

Answer (score 1):

I had sort of the same issue. This:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /folder/$
Disallow: /folder/
```

Did not work for me - the url/folder WOULD appear in the google search results - but it would just say NO INFO or something - nothing from the html page would be indexed. So I tried:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /folder/index.html
Disallow: /folder/*
```

Same thing.

What DID work was to put this meta tag in the index.html file in /folder/:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

With this tag - no links were followed to any other pages or folders but the contents of index.html DID appear.

Comment: Robots.txt doesn't prevent indexing, just crawling.  It sounds like it was working it just wasn't doing what you expected.